# How do I attach a page to a category similar to how we attach media to a post?

Tags: categories, pages

Is it possible/how do I to attach a page to a category similar to how we attach media to a post?

ps. I'm not asking how to assign a category to a page.

update: I need to attach a specific page contents on top of the archive of a specific category archive.

Comment: Using ACF and a [relationship](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/) field is the first thing that comes to mind, if you don't use acf you could use [update_term_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_term_meta/) and add a page id.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast Thanks for this. Could you give me more details (aka an example maybe ) of how to do this with ACF?

Comment: I want to use this to display a page's content on category archive.

Comment: Honestly, the ACF [relationship](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/) documentation is good about explanation and even provides some sample code you can try. Also checkout [Adding fields to a taxonomy term](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/)

Comment: @Pete I've left an answer to the question you asked, but I'm afraid it will not solve your problem, only your question. This appears to be an X Y problem, where you asked how to implement your solution, rather than how to solve the problem. If you share what your actual problem is then you'll get usable answers and save a lot of time. Keep in mind I can only answer the question you wrote. Create a new question, and ask how to solve your problem ( e.g. are you trying to display a pages content at the top of a category? Or redirect to that page? Or show a recommendation? etc )

Comment: If you are asking how to choose and display a page in a category then that has an easy solution that has nothing to do with your question ( multiple solutions actually if you use the block editor and up to date WP some of which require no code )

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes please... that's what i'm trying to do.

Comment: @TomJNowell "are you trying to display a pages content at the top of a category?" Yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, media is attached to posts/pages using the `post_parent` column. This works because media is actually a post of type `attachment` in the database.

Categories however are not posts, and the way you would attach them is by assigning the page to that category.

This leads us to a contradiction, how do you attach a page to a category without attaching it to a category?

I'm sure that your original problem is solvable but this is not the solution.